# When running my django webapp on my local box, why am I getting a blank screen with firefox 7.0.1

Tags: python, django, firefox

I have two web apps written in Django 1.1.  In the past, I have never had problems running them on my local computer via http://127.0.0.1:8000.  Recently, my firefox was upgraded to v. 7.0.1.  Now, from time to time and for various urls, firefox will display a blank screen or a partial screen - something that never happened before.

If I hit the refresh button, the page shows up (some times it takes 3-4 tries).  For development, it's not that big a problem, except that it breaks my Selenium tests.

Any ideas why that might be happening and what solution there could be?

Comment: Does this happen with a different browser?

Comment: @Petr Viktorin:  It hasn't happened with IE.

Comment: Have you validated your pages?  I have seen Safari not show pages correctly that show in firefox/IE because of validation issues.

Comment: @joel goldstick: I haven't validated them, but the problem includes pages that used to work fine but now usually work but sometimes don't, except that, even then, they will work if I refresh the page. It's as if the connection between my browser and localhost gets cut off temporarily.

Comment: you clear browser history and try another port?

Comment: @dustyprogrammer, It looks like changing the port may work.  It's too soon to know for sure, since the problem was only intermittent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something to do with the cache. Have you set the about:config settings so no caching takes place.

Comment: What do you mean by "the about:config settings"?

Comment: OK. I think you meant what is found at the end of this page, and it seems to be working so far ... http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20clear%20the%20cache?s=about%3Aconfig+no-cache&r=0&e=es&as=s

Comment: Apologies I should have better explained.